# Eclipse won't remove bug mark on html files, even when fixed

Tags: html, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse Mars Mac, Java EE, when Eclipse finds a bug in an HTML file, merely fixing the bug does not get Eclipse to remove the red "bug" mark.

Comment: What "bug" mark do you mean?

Comment: The red mark along the left margin, and the red mark indicating that the file has an error

Answer (score 0):

To get fix to be noticed immediately. must delete the buggy text and then replace it.

So, if have

```
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">
```

and the actual path is "../favicon.ico", merely adding the "../" won't get Eclipse to admit the bug is gone.  You must fix the problem, cut it, then paste it back in.

At which point Eclipse will look, see there's no problem, and mark the code appropriatesly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can right-click project -> Validate